# Cycling through tmux panes

Tags: vim, tmux

I am having trouble intuitively cycling through tmux panes. I use `mod-n` and `mod-p`, but I don't like having to execute 2 keypresses.

Recently, I discovered https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator, which works great for navigating tmux splits. Is there a solution for making navigating tmux panes as intuitive (preferably for a Vim user)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.tmux.conf`. The `-n` option  means it is not necessary to use the prefix key (which I assume is the first of the two key presses you're talking about).

```
bind-key -n M-n next-window
bind-key -n M-p previous-window
```

Run `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf` to apply.